# What can I check to see if rspec is running?

Tags: ruby, rspec

So some ruby libraries double as executables, using the trick:

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  # act as executable...
end
```

I'm writing a mini-library, and was wondering if there were a similar trick I could use to embed my rspec tests in the file.  Some sort of constant or something I could check, like:

```
if RSPEC_TARGET == $0
  describe 'Foo' do
    it "should foo" #...
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

`ARGV` contains the name of the script. I use the following in my modules:

```
if ARGV.include? File.basename(__FILE__)
    # unit tests here
end
```

This works because I run my tests with `rspec my_spec.rb`, not `rspec .`